# How to use navigation component when Hilt changes the names of the fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, dagger-hilt

I'm creating an Android app (Java) and using Navigation Components and Hilt for the first time. In the Navigation Editor I'm creating destinations and see that the fragments I created that have been annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint now show as "Hilt_" + the fragment name. Now my app cannot build because the compiler is looking for a constructor with "Hilt_" + the fragment name instead of just the fragment name. Ex: my fragment is named HomeFragment but in the Navigation Editor it is called Hilt_HomeFragment. Error I get when compiling:

```
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.blah.blah.fragment.Hilt_HomeFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
```

How should the name discrepancies be handled so I can use Hilt & navigation components together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hilt_HomeFragment" is a class generated for Hilt purposes, you should not care about it. Just make the `Build` -> `Clean Project`. Then go to your graph, clear the wrong `name` and write the proper one with the full package path. For example:

```
android:name="com.example.home.HomeFragment"
```

When you start typing in the `name` field, Android Studio will show you the prompt with matching fragments you can use - just select the proper one and the `name` will be filled with it.